# Schema.org memberOf error

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

This problem's driving me crazy second day in a row. So, the problem:
I'm trying to use "memberOf" property for "organization", and google structured data tool say that there is error:

> Error: Page contains property "memberOf" which is not part of the schema.

At the same time schema.org says, that this is a property of "organization":

http://schema.org/memberOf

If I change "organization" to "programMembership", no more errors, all good. The problem is that I need to use organization.

The code I'm trying to run on Google tester:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <div itemprop="name">
    NAME 
      <div itemprop="memberOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
         <div itemprop="name">
           NAME2
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see code if you want help debugging it.

Comment: You're missing a > on one of those div tags, although I don't know if that's related to anything. And you should edit the code into the question.

Comment: sorry, first time on this forum. just added, with all "<>"

Comment: No worries! You're doing a better job than most of trying to improve your question. Removed the downvote, I hope you get an answer that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this error. Your use of Microdata and schema.org is valid.

The *Google Structured Data Testing Tool* is probably not up-to-date (it has the [same problem with the `license` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368151/1591669)), maybe because the allowed values of this property changed "recently" (couldn’t find anything about it, just my guess).